# How to change target min3d object android?

Tags: android, object, android-resources, 3ds, min3d

I using min3d example to show object 3ds. But target file = res/raw and texture = assets. Can i replace target file in my external storage? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, here is a framework based on min3d to load from sd https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/tree/master/src/rajawali
Or if you do not want to use another library, look up min3d issue. Some people have proposed a solution
http://code.google.com/p/min3d/issues/detail?id=40